# Return DOM element in render function of React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have an external library that renders some custom js controls. The library returns a DOM element that can be inserted in to the page.

I am creating wrapper for this library in React. I have it all wired up except I'm not sure how to allow the render function to accept the DOM element as its return

```
render() {
 if (this.state.someType) {
   let customControl = new this.state.someType();
   var node = customControl.getNode(); 

   return node; //This is an HTMLDOMElement i.e. div or span
 }

 return <div>Loading Custom Control...</div>;
}
```

I am able to debug the code and everything is working properly. The node is what I expect but the html on the page is never replaced.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Render a normal JSX `div`. Use `ref` inside.

Inside the `ref` callback use `.appendChild(node)`

See https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 31):

Here's a simple example.

```
render() {
   const newNode = document.createElement('p'); 
   return <div ref={(nodeElement) => {nodeElement && nodeElement.appendChild(newNode)}}/>
}
```

Comment: `ref` will also be called when element is unmounted resulting in `nodeElement` being `undefined` for the call. You should include a check `nodeElement && nodeElement.appendChild...`

Comment: This is a good answer as it contains the code example that could go along with the accepted answer. The above commend regarding nodeElement being undefined is also helpful and could be included in this code example.